# How to migrate managed releases of repository from GitHub to gitlab?

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have recently migrated our project from **Github** to **Gitlab.** The repository has been migrated successfully.
Before I ask my question, I would like to tell you one feature of Github **(i.e. Release Management).**

- You can publish an action from a specific release in GitHub Marketplace.
- You can also choose whether Git Large File Storage (Git LFS) objects are included in the ZIP files and tarballs that GitHub creates for each release.

Visit the link for a better understanding of release management.
https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository

Now my **question** is, how to migrate the previously drafted releases from Github to Gitlab?